# How to define a local Java Toolchain in Bazel

Tags: java, bazel, toolchain, bazel-java

I want to use a specific [Azul Zulu JDK](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk#download-openjdk) for my Java builds. Therefore I have stored it in my repository locally e.g. under `tools/zulu19.30.11-ca-jdk19.0.1-macosx_x64`. Now I want to configure a java toolchain target such that I can pass it via `--java_toolchain=//tools:my_custom_java_toolchain`. I don't want to depend on some remote repositories.

What are the required steps to achieve this?

I have found this repository: https://github.com/salesforce/bazel-jdt-java-toolchain/blob/main/jdt/defs.bzl which defines a target of type `default_java_toolchain` but I can not derive something useful for my use case. I don't know e.g. what the field `header_compiler` means. My naive assumption is that I just have to pass some paths to the required tools (such as `bin/javac`) for java compilation.

My current approach uses the rules `java_toolchain` and `java_runtime`. My BUILD file looks like this:

```
java_runtime(
  name = "zulu19.30.11-ca-jdk19.0.1-macosx_x64",
  srcs = glob(["zulu19.30.11-ca-jdk19.0.1-macosx_x64/**"]),
  java_home = "zulu19.30.11-ca-jdk19.0.1-macosx_x64",
)

java_toolchain(
  name = "zulu-19",
  source_version = "19",
  target_version = "19",
  java_runtime = ":zulu19.30.11-ca-jdk19.0.1-macosx_x64",
  javabuilder = "",
  ijar = "",
  singlejar = "",
  genclass = "",
)
```

I am trying to execute the command: `bazel build --extra_toolchains="//tools:zulu-19" //:ProjectRunner` and it complains about the missing mandatory attributes `javabuilder`, `ijar`, `singlejar` and `genclass` but I have no idea which are the correct paths or values.

I'm just wondering how bazel knows how to compile the java code with these few information. Why I don't have to specify `javac` for example?

Answer (score 1):

Basically I came up with the following solution which seems to solve my problem and is inspired by the rule `default_java_toolchain`. I used the existing targets for `javabuilder`, `ijar`, `singlejar` and `genclass` which are defined in `@bazel_tools//tools/jdk`. Note that I had to use `BASE_JDK9_JVM_OPTS` for a successful build.

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:default_java_toolchain.bzl", "BASE_JDK9_JVM_OPTS")

java_runtime(
  name = "zulu19.30.11-ca-jdk19.0.1-macosx_x64",
  srcs = glob(["zulu19.30.11-ca-jdk19.0.1-macosx_x64/**"]),
  java_home = "zulu19.30.11-ca-jdk19.0.1-macosx_x64",
)

config_setting(
  name = "zulu-19-runtime_version_setting",
  values = {"java_runtime_version": "19"},
  visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
)

toolchain(
  name = "zulu-19_runtime_toolchain_definition",
  target_settings = ["zulu-19-runtime_version_setting"],
  toolchain_type = "@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:runtime_toolchain_type",
  toolchain = "zulu19.30.11-ca-jdk19.0.1-macosx_x64",
)

java_toolchain(
  name = "zulu-19",
  source_version = "19",
  target_version = "19",
  java_runtime = ":zulu19.30.11-ca-jdk19.0.1-macosx_x64",
  jvm_opts = BASE_JDK9_JVM_OPTS,
  javabuilder = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:javabuilder"],
  ijar = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:ijar"],
  singlejar = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:singlejar"],
  genclass = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:genclass"],
)

config_setting(
  name = "zulu-19_version_setting",
  values = {"java_language_version": "19"},
  visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
)

toolchain(
  name = "zulu-19_toolchain_definition",
  toolchain_type = "@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:toolchain_type",
  target_settings = ["zulu-19_version_setting"],
  toolchain = "zulu-19",
)
```

The following command now successfully runs without any errors. `System.out.println(Runtime.version());` also prints the correct version.

```
bazel run --extra_toolchains="//tools:zulu-19_toolchain_definition,//tools:zulu-19_runtime_toolchain_definition" --java_language_version="19" --java_runtime_version="19" //:ProjectRunner
```

But I still have a couple of questions, e.g. why `javabuilder`, `ijar`, `singlejar` and `genclass` are needed and what is the purpose of those targets? How does the toolchain target know about my `javac` binary for compiling the java code? Why do I have to use `BASE_JDK9_JVM_OPTS` for a successful build and can I omit some settings?